# Dynamics CRM 4.0 - Number of days in month?

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, crm

I was just wondering if anyone knew the number of days that Dynamics CRM defines as 1 month when it comes to work flows.

I am currently developing a workflow that requires some date checking and need to verify something at the 150 day mark.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes, the Dynamic Values picker in the Workflow builder saves to a `CrmTimeSpan` type.  When a `CrmTimeSpan`/`TimeSpan` is used, months are stored as months, not a sum of days.  For example:

```
DateTime firstOfTheYear = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1);

CrmTimeSpan timespan = CrmTimeSpan.CreateCrmTimeSpan(0,1,0,0,0);

DateTime firstDayOfFebruary = timespan.Add(firstOfTheYear);

DateTime firstDayOfMarch = timespan.Add(firstDayOfFebruary);
```

Because you need to check against a date range that isn't supported by the picker, [here is a custom workflow activity](http://danielcai.blogspot.com/2010/05/mscrm-40-offset-crm-dates-in-workflow.html) that should get you on the right track.